# SQL Case in Where Clause with between operator

Tags: sql, case

I need to get a set of records based on the below points:

1. If (`startdate` and `endate` are not null then `opendate` shoudl be between `startdate` an`d enddate`) or (`closedate` should be between `startdate` and `enddate`)
2. If `startdate` is not null and `enddate` is null then `opendate = startdate`
3. If `startdate` is null and `enddate` is not null then `closedate = enddate`
4. If both `startdate` and `enddate` is null then it should retrieve all data

I tried this using the query below but it satisfied only Points 2 through 4.

```
Select * From CheckDateValues C
Where 
1 = 1 and

C.OPenDate >= Case 
             When (@OpenDate IS NULL) THEN C.OpenDate Else @OpenDate
             End
and 
C.CloseDate <= Case 
          When (@CloseDate IS NULL) THEN C.CloseDate Else @CloseDate
          End
```

I'm not sure how to write the query to get Point 1 to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to determine some form of overlap between two ranges - one in the tables columns, and the other in your variables. If so, I'll give you my usual test for overlap:

```
Select * From CheckDateValues C
where C.OpenDate <= COALESCE(@CloseDate,C.CloseDate) and
COALESCE(@OpenDate,C.OpenDate) <= C.CloseDate
```

Which (using [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to eliminate `NULL` values from variables) boils down to:

Two periods overlap if:

- the *start* of period 1 is before the *end* of period 2, **and**
- the *start* of period 2 is before the *end* of period 1.

This is a far simpler definition than most people usually come up with and avoids enumerating lots of cases.